# Validar un texto con jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 5, jquery 3.1 tengo un formulario en el cual tengo un control input, el cual solo necesito que me permita ingresar solo números.

Código jquery

```
<script>
$('#NumeroDocumento').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (!$.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

¿No se por qué no esta funcionando?

Comment: Coloca en un `alert(String.fromCharCode(e.which));` o en un `console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which));` para comprobar qué valor tienes en esa línea.

Comment: y si le pones un type=number?

Comment: @fredyfx el razor es el que genera el código como puedo ponerle algo como me indicas?

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione me faltaba modificar una linea de código.

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```